# Sum up data from facts

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

(Given a list of movies, write a PROLOG rule to add and display the total takings.)
This is my question I am basically trying to add an integer value give a list of movies from the list below. I am quite new in Prolog and I don't really understand how things work.

```
takings(air_force_one,315000000).
takings(american_beauty,336000000).
takings(american_pie,201700000).
takings(american_wedding,230700000).
takings(armageddon,554600000).
takings(as_good_as_it_gets,313300000).
takings(austin_powers_in_goldmember,289000000).
takings(babe,249000000).
takings(back_to_the_future,350600000).
takings(back_to_the_future_part_ii,332000000).
takings(back_to_the_future_part_iii,243700000).
takings(robots,245600000).
takings(hulk,241700000).
takings(bad_boys_ii,261900000).
```

The Rule I have written so far works for only one movie.
Example:

```
?-  score([robots],Y).
    Y = 245600000.

?- score([robots,hulk],Y).
false.

?- score([robots,hulk,bad_boys__ii],Y).
false.
```

Rule written :

```
score([Movies], Money):-
    findall(Profit,(takings(Movies, Profit)), ListOfProfit),
    sum_list(ListOfProfit, Money).
```

---

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60582468/1243762) asking for a recursive answer.

Comment: Hint: use`[H|T]` as pattern to unify with the head of the list, and the tail.

Comment: I have no idea where to implement this to my rule