# Prolog findall/3 rule convert to recursive rule

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

```
score(Movies,Total) :-
    findall(Money,(member(Movie,Movies),takings(Movie,Money)),Profit),
    sum_list(Profit,Total)
```

I want to convert this rule using recursion but I am not sure how. Help!
Link to the previous question that answers this one : [Sum up data from facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580787/sum-up-data-from-facts/60581149#60581149)

Answer (score 3):

```
% base case
score([],0).
% recursive case
score([Movie|Movies],Total) :-
    takings(Movie,Profit),
    score(Movies,Total0),
    Total is Total0 + Profit.
```

Example run

```
?- score([robots,hulk,bad_boys_ii],Y).
Y = 749200000.
```

**Explanation of code**

List in Prolog are recursively constructed and deconstructed using the **|** operator. As 0 is the initial value for counting integers, **[ ]**, known as the empty list, is the initial value for a closed list. To recursively build to the front of a closed list one uses the current list and the **|** operator. When using **|** in Prolog it is common to refer to the item being added as the **Head**, (H) and the current closed list being added to as the **Tail**, (T), and this why you often see the notation **[H|T]** when talking about list in Prolog.

So to construct the list [1,2,3] would be [] then add 1, [1].

```
?- L = [1|[]].
L = [1].
```

To add 2 would be [1] then add 2, [2,1].

```
?- L = [2|[1]].
L = [2, 1].
```

To deconstruct the list [1,2,3] would use variables so [H|T] will become H being 1 with T being [2,3].

```
?- [H|T] = [1,2,3].
H = 1,
T = [2, 3].
```

When you get to the end of the list it is just [] with out a head.

```
?- [H|T] = [1].
H = 1,
T = [].
```

So in the code `[Movie|Movies]` takes input list of movies and unifies the head of the list `Movie` with the first movie and passes the tail of the list `Movies` recursively to the predicate. Only when the list is empty will the clause `score([],0)` match and unify the 0 with `Total0` in `score(Movies,Total0)`.

I know this can have a lot more detail in explanations, but these explanations are all over the place in Prolog examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me.

Comment: @ZisisKostakakis It was odd that you were closer to solving it your first time using findall instead of recursion. Many people have a hard time understanding findall/3 at first until they see a few examples, and good findall examples are not easy to find.

Comment: @ZisisKostakakis Don't forget to up-vote the answer you like and click the check mark next to answers that give you the correct answer.

Comment: I found it easier to use findall that I self-taught than using [H|T] where I hardly understand

Comment: i will agree with you that the instructor is not the best at explaining as English is not his/her main language.

Answer (score 0):

This way :)

```
recursive_score([H], CurrentMoney):-
    takings(H, Value),
    CurrentMoney is Value.
recursive_score([H|T], Money):-
    takings(H, Value),
    recursive_score(T, CurrentMoney),
    Money is CurrentMoney + Value.
```

Comment: If you new at Prolog, you can examine [my prolog homework](https://github.com/yusufbayrakdar/Pokemon_Prolog), it will teach you basics of Prolog

Comment: While the OP did not specify what should happen with an empty list, would it not be better to return 0, than `false` with an empty list?

Comment: Stop being angry, I was trying to help :( it is true there is no explanation but he/she can search and it is let he/she learn better.